# .NET c# ConvertTimeToUtc fails sending to Firestore when using TimeZone UTC+0

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, timezone

To store DateTime in Google Firestore, you must first convert to UTC. However this does not work with the TimeZone of UTC+0, but works for all other TimeZones.

**Example 1: myTimeZone is (UTC+01:00) Casablanca**

```
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;

DateTime localDate = new DateTime(2020, 12, 01);
DateTime utcDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDate, myTimeZone);

Debug.WriteLine("TimeZone: " + myTimeZone);
Debug.WriteLine("localDate : " + localDate.ToString() + " " + localDate.Kind);
Debug.WriteLine("utcDate: " + utcDate.ToString() + " " + utcDate.Kind);

WriteBatch batch = db.StartBatch();
dynamic dataObject = new ExpandoObject();
dataObject.startDate = utcDate;
batch.Set(dataReference, dataObject, SetOptions.MergeAll);
```

Output:

```
TimeZone: (UTC+01:00) Casablanca
localDate: 1/12/2020 12:00:00 AM Unspecified
utcDate: 30/11/2020 11:00:00 PM Utc
```

Data sends correctly.

**Example 2: myTimeZone is (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London**

Same code as above.

Output:

```
TimeZone: (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
localDate: 1/12/2020 12:00:00 AM Unspecified
utcDate: 1/12/2020 12:00:00 AM Utc

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Google.Protobuf.dll
System.ArgumentException: Conversion from DateTime to Timestamp requires the DateTime kind to be Utc
Parameter name: dateTime
   at Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime dateTime) in T:\src\github\protobuf\csharp\src\Google.Protobuf\WellKnownTypes\TimestampPartial.cs:line 150
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.DateTimeConverter.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Converters/SimpleConverters.cs:line 173
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.ValueSerializer.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/ValueSerializer.cs:line 49
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.DictionaryConverter`1.SerializeMap(SerializationContext context, Object value, IDictionary`2 map) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Converters/DictionaryConverter.cs:line 65
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.MapConverterBase.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Converters/MapConverterBase.cs:line 35
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.ValueSerializer.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/ValueSerializer.cs:line 49
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.ListConverterBase.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Converters/ListConverterBase.cs:line 36
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.ValueSerializer.Serialize(SerializationContext context, Object value) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/ValueSerializer.cs:line 49
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Converters.DictionaryConverter`1.SerializeMap(SerializationContext context, Object value, IDictionary`2 map) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Converters/DictionaryConverter.cs:line 65
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.ValueSerializer.SerializeMap(SerializationContext context, Object value) in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/ValueSerializer.cs:line 61
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.WriteBatch.Set(DocumentReference documentReference, Object documentData, SetOptions options)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , WriteBatch , DocumentReference , Object , SetOptions )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
```

I have confirmed that the code works correctly for ALL other TimeZones, except UTC+0.

I'm using .Net 4.7.2 and Google.Cloud.Firestore 2.3.0

Any ideas how to fix? Or a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi.  In the code you showed, the only value passed to the FireStore SDK is `utcDate` - which doesn't carry any time zone information.  It only caries the value and the kind.  Since you showed the kind as UTC in both cases, so I can only conclude that you're not showing the actual code reproducing the problem.  Also, `dataObject` would have to use `dynamic`, not `var` so the code you gave does not compile.  Please update your question to be a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).   Please initialize all values, or at least show their types.  Thanks.

Comment: I've added data types, but the code is full and complete. You only need to pass a utcDate to FireStore and it automatically converts to a Timestamp. That is where the bug is, with the FireStore date convertor, please see the error message.

Comment: Please could you provide a [mcve]? Your snippet uses `dataReference` which isn't defined, and in trying to reproduce this I'm getting a dynamic binding error with the call to `batch.Set`. I can fix that with a cast, but then I can't reproduce the issue. Here's an example of what I'm looking for: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/ab54ac628671656e785210b5141a666e - that produces the same output as example 2, but doesn't throw an exception for me.

Comment: Any update on this? Without a [mcve], it's going to be hard to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was already reported [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175301081).
I created an internal case with the Firebase team.
You can use this issuetracker to track fixing progress or for further communication.

Comment: That is not my issue. My issue is the FireStore DateTime convertor does not work for a TimeZone of UTC + 0. It does work for all other TimeZone values.

Comment: You are right. I created a new issue and edited the answer.